# I'm getting error while sending the verification code from firebase Phone Auth

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Application crashes on .sendVerificationCode and .onCreate method

Logcat:

```
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)

at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(Unknown Source:7)

at com.studyhours.studystudios.activities.VerifyPhone.sendVerificationCode(VerifyPhone.java:144)

at com.studyhours.studystudios.activities.VerifyPhone.onCreate(VerifyPhone.java:137)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8151)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8135)
```

I'm getting error at onCreate and sendVerificationCode, I want to register the user by email and password and send them to verify phone number Activity to verify the number before proceeding to the MainActivity.

After creating and calling the sendVerificationCode method it sends the OTP but crashes at the same time

My Java Code:

````
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_phone);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

//        Passing and Storing the phone number from the user activity
        final String phonenumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phonenumber");


        final TextView otpPhone = findViewById(R.id.otpPhone);
        resendOtp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resendBtn);


        // getting email and phone from Register activity through intent
        final String getPhone = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");

        // setting email and phone to TextView
        otpPhone.setText(getPhone);

        findViewById(R.id.verifyBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String code = editText1.getText().toString() +
                        editText2.getText().toString() +
                        editText3.getText().toString() +
                        editText4.getText().toString() +
                        editText5.getText().toString() +
                        editText6.getText().toString();



                if (code.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(VerifyPhone.this, "Please enter the code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        });


        resendOtp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // handling resend code here
                resendOtp(phonenumber);

            }
        });

        // calling send OTP
        sendVerificationCode(phonenumber);

    }

    public void sendVerificationCode(String number)
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                number,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                this,
                mCallBack
        );

    }

    ```
````

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AlexMamo edited, please help me getting this error to be solved.